# При добавлении данных в таблицу прерывается работа программы

Tags: c#, winforms

Я создал приложение и добавил в него возможность добавлять рецепты в базу данных, но как только нажимаю на кнопку добавления в бд, получаю вот такую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Типы вводимых данных совпадают с теми что в бд.
Так почему тогда я получил эту ошибку?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class PlusRecepies : Form
    {
        public PlusRecepies()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PlusToFlp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var label1 = new Label();
            flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(label1);
            label1.Text = ProductPlus.Text;
        }

        public void AddRecipe()
        {
            Db1Context context = new Db1Context();
            Recipe recipe = new Recipe
            {
                Instructions = RecepiePRText.Text,
                Name = NameRecipe.Text,
                Prop_Time = Convert.ToDouble(PropTime.Text)
            };

            context.Recipe.Add(recipe);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        private void AddRecepieToDB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddRecipe();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот в этой строке `Prop_Time = Convert.ToDouble(PropTime.Text)` чему равно `PropTime.Text` ?

Comment: PropTime.Text это строка но я ее конвертировал в Double.

Comment: Я вижу код, я спрашиваю, какое именно значение строковое вы конвертируете в double?

Comment: @OleksandrTatarinov
Чему равно значение PropTime.Text? судя по названию явно не double.

Comment: @temiklis https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1600 там и так Parse под капотом

Comment: Приведите пример того, что вы вводите в PropTime

Comment: Похоже на классическую ошибку с неверным форматом разделителя числа с плавающей точкой.

Comment: В PropTime ввожу 2.2

Comment: тогда `Convert.ToDouble("0.222", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: Хотя вам лучше определиться с культурой, возможно, выставить её при старте приложения